# Pandas - Merge 2 dataframes, only with columns from the first dataframe as output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Say I have one dataframe with columns as follows:

| A | B | C | X | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

and the other dataframe has columns:

| A | J | L | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

How can I add the rows from the second dataframe onto the first that only has 5 columns? I don't want columns J and L to be in the final dataframe.

Also assume there are many other columns i don't want, so is there a way to this without specifying column names? It'll be massive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html) for filter columns from `df2` by `df1.columns`:

```
#if all columns from df1 are in df2
df22 = df2[df1.columns]
#if NOT all columns from df1 are in df2
df22 = df2[df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)]
```

And then use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
df = df1.append(df22, ignore_index=True)
```

Or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df22], ignore_index=True)
```

---

Another solution is filter after append new rows by columns in `df1`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)[df1.columns]
```

Comment: I edited the question if that helps. So df22 = df2[df2.columns.intersection(df1.columns)] then df = pd.concat([df1, df22], ignore_index=True)?

Comment: we basically say want A | B | C | X | F, where A, B, and C are added as rows onto df1 but X and F can just be NaN for those entries

Comment: @caasswa - exactly you are right.

Comment: if you had 3 dataframes with df1 being what you want in terms of columns, you can do `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], ignore_index=True)[df1.columns]` i guess right? :)

Comment: @caasswa - yop, you are right.